# Custom search page wont allow URL params

Tags: search

I am trying to create a custom search page but having issues.

I have a file called "searchpage.php" which is set as the default page for a page created in the WP Admin called 'search'.

I am trying to call the URL: /search?s=test

However, the browser changes this URL to: search/?s=test which 404's.

If I rename my searchpage.php to search.php and just use the URL: ?s=test everything works fine and my search page shows correctly. I would however like the page to have search before the term so thats its more recognisable and relevant to the user.

I achieved this on another project but no matter what I do I cannot get it working on this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own [Custom Endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) or [Rewrite Rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to capture the s param. Then route it to your search page with a [Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) applied or hook the [Template Redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect).

Comment: Thanks, the custom endpoint got me somewhere. The search page now works, but pagination doesn't. When visiting /search/?s=term&paged=2 it changes the URL to: search/page/2/?s=term. Any help with that one

Comment: It's probably best to mark the question answered and post another question with the code you used.